# Javascript change certain words on web pages

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom, web

I'm trying to grab all the nodes in the DOM and if its text, change the value of certain words to something else. The code is not doing anything and I don't understand why. Please help.

```
 var elements=document.getElementsByTagName('*');

 for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++){

var element=elements[i];

for(var j=0;j<element.childNodes.length;j++){

    var node=element.childNodes[j];
    if(node.nodeType==3){
        var text=node.nodeValue;
        var replacedText=text.replace(/jacob/g, 'toolshed')
        if(replacedText!=text){
            console.log('replaced');
            element.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(replacedText),node);
            //node.nodeValue=replacedText;
        }

      }

    }

 }
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce; your code works for me! https://jsfiddle.net/Ltb88xp2/ Maybe you could show a complete simple example? (i.e., show some specific HTML input that doesn't work)

Comment: this code is in my chrome extension in the content script